# How to combine two manifests to a file in AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, manifest

I have train.manifest and validation.manifest in my S3 bucket. I need to combine them to a file, but I don't know how to combine them

Comment: s3 is an object store, so you have first read them individually and combine them through some logic/append them to a file and push this file to s3.

Comment: Not with S3. You need to write some code in a service, lambda, whatever that takes care of that.